# Spy Game Help, Python

Tags: python, for-loop

This are the rules:
SPY GAME: Write a function that takes in a list of integers and returns True if it contains 007 in order

```
 spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5]) --> True
 spy_game([1,0,2,4,0,5,7]) --> True
 spy_game([1,7,2,0,4,5,0]) --> False

#functions to check if it works
spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5])
spy_game([1,0,2,4,0,5,7])
spy_game([1,7,2,0,4,5,0])
```

The first and last check works but the second doesn't "spy_game([1,0,2,4,0,5,7])",

After it has found the second 0, 5 and 7 are left but my code doen't check 7 and exits the loop after 5.

The prints like "print('first',i)" prints the position it has found the number.

I added an extra print k at the end to see where the loop stops and it stops at 5 which is #5 in the list, the loop exits before getting to 7 to return True.

```
def spy_game(nums): 
    
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i] == 7:
            return False
        elif nums[i] == 0:
            print('first',i)
            for j in range(i+1,len(nums)-1): #3 - 6
                if nums[j] == 7:
                    return False
                elif nums[j] == 0:
                    print('second',j)
                    for k in range(j+1,len(nums)-1): #5 -
                        print(k)
                        if nums[k] != 7:
                            continue
                        else:
                            print('third',k)
                            return True
                    return False
```

I also had the end of the loop like this but the same happened:

```
for k in range(j+1,len(nums)-1): 
       if nums[k] == 7:
         return True 
return False
```

[image: Enters for i, for j and in for k it only loops once, doesn't loop the 7 just the 5]

Comment: Use `len(nums)` in `range`, not `len(nums)-1`, the last bound is *exclusive* already.

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to find the problem yourself first before posting. Specifically what part of the code appears to do something different form what you expect? What is it doing; what do you think it should be doing instead; and why?

Comment: If you have [1,0,2,7,0,5,7], how it should behave? return False or True?

Comment: Hint: where the code says `range(j+1,len(nums)-1)`, exactly what do you expect this to mean? What numbers do you think will be used for `k`, and why? Now, **test** that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I'm not helping you to cheat in a test or something like that.

Explaining my snippet: I have a list of items to find (to_find), and I loop through the list only once, searching for the first element of to_find: whenever I find it, I remove it (first element) from to_find.
If all to_find elements are found, return true. Else, return false

```
def spy_game(values):
    to_find = [0,0,7]
    for k in values:
        if k == to_find[0]:
            to_find.pop(0)
            if len(to_find) == 0:
                return True
        
    return False

print(spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5])) # true
print(spy_game([1,0,2,4,0,5,7])) # true
print(spy_game([1,7,2,0,4,5,0])) # false
print(spy_game([1,0,2,7,0,5,7])) # unmentioned case - true
```

Comment: Thankyou very much! It is for a coruse in udemy, but i have not received any answer from there! :)